# Querying a ManytoOne Relationship using @Query in Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have Employees table which has many-to-one relationship to Company table ( similar to my situation). I am currently using Spring Data Repositories.

Now I am a bit confused on how to get employees matching join-date and Employer Id . As it is a many to one relation, Employees Entity has a Employer Entity with the mapping.

I thought of using @Query Annotation with a query like below:

```
@Query(Select emp from Employee emp where emp.joindate= ?1 and emp.employer.id =?2)
Employees methodname ( arg1, arg2)
```

Any Corrections or Suggestions ? . I don’t see good documentation on @Query. Please post if u have gone thru one

Comment: what's wrong with your solution?

Comment: I want to find out if it’s the right way ? Also I don’t see any documentation on how these queries work internally, I mean how the joins are done

Comment: You don't need `@Query`. You can do this just with method name

Comment: Makes sense. Is that because method names also check on nested properties ?.

Comment: *I want to find out if it’s the right way?*: write a test to check that. You won't find any documentation about JPQL in the Spring-data-jpa documentation. Spring-data-jpa is just a thin abstraction layer on top of JPA. Read the documentation of Hibernate, or the JPA specifications, for example, to learn JPQL.

Comment: @Kranthi method names are just a convenience provided by spring-data, they run queries just like if they were JPA method calls. So if you have the nested properties annotated with `ManyToOne` the query methods will fetch them (according to the declared fetch type)